# Differences between $.ajax type put and model.save in backbone.js?

Tags: serialization, backbone.js, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

There seems to be some differences between saving a model using this.model.save() and using jquery ajax type PUT?

I have the following method in my api controller

```
public void Put(string id, [FromBody]IContent value) {
    // save
}
```

I have also enabled TypeNameHandling on JSON formatter serializer setting like this:

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto;
```

If I PUT some data using jquery ajax like this

```
$.ajax({  
    url: "/api/page/articles/1",  
    type: "PUT",  
    dataType: "json",  
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify({"$type": "BrickPile.Samples.Models.Article,BrickPile.Samples","id": "articles/1", "heading": "Some heading..." })
});
```

my object binds correct in the put method but when I try to save my object using model.save() in backbone the input value is null and it cannot bind the object?

This is how I do it:

```
this.model.set({ heading: 'foo' });
this.model.save();
```

the request headers seem to look ok and the payload is seems to be JSON, at least if I look in firebug. It's also possible to PUT some data to my api using fiddler with the same payload but not if I copy the payload source from firebug see: http://cl.ly/Nked

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about your model implementation it is hard to say for sure. One thing I can see from your firebug screenshot is that the id attribute is being passed as `"articles/1"` which is unusual for standard Backbone. If you were saving a model object then the id would normally be `"1"`. So a `model.save()` would generate a HTTP PUT to `articles/1` and pass the json as something including `{"id":"1", ... }`. The [Backbone.sync](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync) documentation has more details on the default behaviour.